# lua, call script from C with limited modules, error on string.len

Tags: lua

I am testing about calling LUA scripts from C. LUA 5.3.5.

To tighten the libraries used, in C I am using

```
L = luaL_newstate();
luaopen_base(L);
luaopen_string(L);
luaL_dofile(L, szFilename);
int tipo = lua_getglobal(L, "check");
int error = lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
```

(code simplified and without error handling)

This is the sample LUA script:

```
function check()
        local buffer = "hello"
        buffer = buffer .. " world!"
        print(buffer)
        print(string.len(buffer))
end
```

Why does *string.len* return error?

> attempt to index a nil value (global 'string')

I thought *luaopen_string* loads the string library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking on the LUA mailing list, the best hint I got is to look at the source code.

*luaL_openlibs* is defined in *linit.c*

```
LUALIB_API void luaL_openlibs (lua_State *L) {
  const luaL_Reg *lib;
  /* "require" functions from 'loadedlibs' and set results to global table */
  for (lib = loadedlibs; lib->func; lib++) {
    luaL_requiref(L, lib->name, lib->func, 1);
    lua_pop(L, 1);  /* remove lib */
  }
}
```

So to load only the libraries *base* and *string*
the solution for LUA 5.3 is

```
 luaL_requiref(L, "_G", luaopen_base, 1);
 lua_pop(L, 1);
 luaL_requiref(L, LUA_STRLIBNAME, luaopen_string, 1);
 lua_pop(L, 1);
```

And for LUA 5.4

```
 luaL_requiref(L, LUA_GNAME, luaopen_base, 1);
 lua_pop(L, 1);
 luaL_requiref(L, LUA_STRLIBNAME, luaopen_string, 1);
 lua_pop(L, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

`luaopen_string` does not define a global variable `string`: it just leaves the table on the stack. So do

```
luaopen_string(L);
lua_setglobal(L,"string");
```

Alternatively, use [luaL_requiref](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_requiref) instead of calling `luaopen_string` directly:

```
luaL_requiref(L,"string", luaopen_string,1);
```

See the last paragraph of [section 6](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6) in the manual;

> To have access to these libraries, the C host program should call the `luaL_openlibs` function, which opens all standard libraries. Alternatively, the host program can open them individually by using luaL_requiref to call  ... `luaopen_string` (for the string library) ... These functions are declared in lualib.h.

Finally, if you want to customize the set of standard libraries that your program uses, edit [linit.c](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/linit.c.html) and add it to your project. Change the list in [loadedlibs](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/linit.c.html#loadedlibs). Then call `luaL_openlibs`.

Comment: I call *lua_setglobal* and *require* is useless. Very good, I don't need to luaopen_package. BTW, I have to call also *lua_setglobal(L,"base")* ?

Comment: Do you know a good "calling LUA from C" primer? I google and find many results, most of all are outdated or useless.

Comment: You don't need to call `lua_setglobal(L,"base")`. And it would be `lua_setglobal(L,"_G")`, but this is done by `luaopen_base`.

Comment: The standard reference is the book [Programming in Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/).

Comment: Pls another question. *luaopen_string* + *lua_setglobal* balance the stack. Calling only *luaopen_base* the stack has one element... should I pop it ?